# Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'jetty' not found

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, jetty

Yesterday I upgraded Android Studio to version 3.0, but I'm working with LibGdx and after the upgrade I cannot build my project.

When I'm try to build, it gives me an error:

> Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'jetty' not found

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Currently **html module** using deprecated `jetty plugin` which is removed in Gradle 4.1 version.

Android Studio 3.0 using `Gradle-4.1` and `android-gradle-plugin:3.0.0`

Gradle 4.1 is not supported yet in LibGDX, there is an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698) for the same, which is now [upgraded](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5177) for Gradle 4.6

---

If you still want to use Android Studio 3.0

- Downgrade Gradle to 3.3 from 4.1

  Find gradle folder inside your project, Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change distributionUrl for 3.3

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
  ```
- Downgrade Android-gradle-plugin to 2.3.3 from 3.0.0

  Open root `build.gradle` file and find artifact and change version

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  ```
- Comment/delete `google()` from repo list

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT** : Update LibGDX project to Gradle 4.6 - AS USER

1. Upgrade Gradle to 4.6 :

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
   ```
2. Find root `build.gradle` file of your project and add Google's Maven repo in `project repositories list` as well as in `buildScript repo list`

   ```
   repositories {
       //.. 
       google()
       jcenter()         // Required for org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j library
   }
   ```
3. Update Android Gradle Plugin :

   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

   **Known issues with the Android Gradle Plugin**

   > Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above:
   >
   > If you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6
   >   and above, you should disable configuration on demand to avoid some
   >   unpredictable build errors. (If you are using Android Gradle Plugin
   >   3.2.0 or higher, you do not need to take any action to disable configuration on demand.)

   Disable configuration on demand in your `gradle.properties` file as shown below:

   - `org.gradle.configureondemand=false`
   - To disable configuration on demand in the Android Studio settings, choose File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences on Mac), select the Compiler category in the left pane, and clear the Configure on demand checkbox.

     In Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 and higher, the options for enabling configuration on demand have been removed.
4. Update Android buildToolsVersion to `27.0.3` and SdkVersion to `27`
5. Remove `instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')`  from `sourceSets` inside android `build.gradle` file
6. replace all `compile` with `implementation` inside root `build.gradle` file
7. New `GWT Gradle Plugin` added in html module, check latest [build.gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-gwt/build.gradle) of html module.

Run your project with `Run Configuration` or On Terminal using `gradle task`.

---

If you're going to create new project use `gdx-setup.jar` of [latest build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/).

Comment: Great, this helped! Is there a way to find out what update is safe to apply before it crashes your project?

Comment: crashes ?? If you're talking about desktop crash, you can use Terminal to run your desktop project.

Comment: After the update I was not able to build the project at all. That's the crash I'm talking about. I would like to know what update is safe before I run it.

Comment: I downgraded Gradle as you explained and it works well again. Error was the same as Eugenio explained at his question at top.

Comment: Can you run the Desktop module also with this fix?

Comment: @Julien yes, you can run desktop module

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks worked for me too, just found the "gradle-wrapper.properties" inside folder "gradle/wrapper" and found both "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1" and "google()" in the "build.gradle" file. Hope this helps, because everyone is expected to come to this answer whose not familiar with gradle options. Good Day

Comment: Worked for me too. If you get an error like "Error:(74, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'" make sure to replace all the 'implementation' calls back to 'compile' in build.gradle projects dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from Jetty Plugin team is to switch to gretty

Please check this
[Error while replacing jetty plugin to gretty plugin gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119925/error-while-replacing-jetty-plugin-to-gretty-plugin-gradle)

Comment: Instead of experimenting yourself, simply upgrade to to libGDX' changed Gradle 4.6 toolchain.