# Error while replacing jetty plugin to gretty plugin gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, gradle-plugin, gretty

I have a JAX-RS project which have jetty plugin in gradle. I want to replace jetty plugin with gretty as jetty is not supported in gradle 4 and other versions. I get following errors while running gretty plugin.

Execution failed for task ':appRunWar'.

> java.lang.Exception: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider

build.gradle code containing jetty plugin

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
jettyRun {
    httpPort = 8080
    reload = 'automatic'
    scanIntervalSeconds = 2
    daemon = false
}
//other things....
```

build.gradle code for replacing jetty with gretty

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    //contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'
    httpEnabled = true
}
//other things...
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, do not use [Akhikhl's](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty) gretty since its not maintained anymore and shows difficulties with certain jetty versions eg. jetty94 and jetty93. Additionally there is no support for Java versions 9 and 10. 
Instead you should rely on the [gretty-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty) which is a direct maintained fork:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.1.0'
}

gretty {
    //contextPath = '/'
}

//other things...
```

The configuration you provide for gretty is the default configuration, you can drop it.
The default configuration in the `ServerConfig.groovy` looks like the following:

```
static ServerConfig getDefaultServerConfig(String serverName) {
    ServerConfig result = new ServerConfig()
    result.jvmArgs = []
    result.servletContainer = 'jetty9'
    result.managedClassReload = false
    result.httpEnabled = true
    result.httpsEnabled = false
    result.interactiveMode = 'stopOnKeyPress'
    result.scanInterval = 1
    result.loggingLevel = 'INFO'
    result.consoleLogEnabled = true
    result.fileLogEnabled = true
    result.logFileName = serverName
    result.redeployMode = 'restart'
    result.logDir = "${System.getProperty('user.home')}/logs" as String
    result.scanner = 'jetty'
    result.portPropertiesFileName = 'gretty_ports.properties'
    result.liveReloadEnabled = false
    return result
}
```

Be aware that the gretty-gradle-plugin can be found at `'org.gretty'` where as Akhikhl's gretty is located at `'org.akhikhl.gretty'`. If your error persists please provide a full stacktrace and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo please show us your configuration